# Why are clones moving but not original?

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Jokris82/pen/RwaaZJP)

If I click on the box it will receive the class ".selected".
If I then press key "x", it will create clones of itself.
And if pressing the "up" arrow on my keyboard, the clones move up. But why doesn't the original square move up?

```
body.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 38) { // up
        var allSelected = document.querySelectorAll(".selected");
        for (var i = 0; i < allSelected.length; i++) {
            var currentPos = allSelected[i].style.top;
            var newPos = currentPos.slice(0, -2) // remove px
            newPos = parseInt(newPos); // make int
            newPos -= 30;
            newPos = newPos + "px";
            allSelected[i].style.top = newPos;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried the codepen, nothing moves up.

Comment: Use `var currentPos = getComputedStyle(allSelected[i]).top;` instead of `var currentPos = allSelected[i].style.top;` because the original box doesn't have an inline style so `.style.top` will be `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original element doesn't have `style.top` and newPos is "NaNpx" due to that.

```
body.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 38) { // up
        var allSelected = document.querySelectorAll(".selected");
        for (var i = 0; i < allSelected.length; i++) {
            var currentPos = allSelected[i].style.top;

             if(!currentPos) {
                currentPos = allSelected[i].offsetTop + 'px';
             }

            var newPos = currentPos.slice(0, -2) // remove px
            newPos = parseInt(newPos); // make int
            newPos -= 30;
            newPos = newPos + "px";
            allSelected[i].style.top = newPos;
        }
    }
});
```